# Detect max video resolution support for a mobile device on responsive website

Tags: android, ios, mobile, video, html5-video

As the title says, I'm searching for cross-browser and mostly cross-platform solution for displaying html5 videos **of different size resolutions**. My main issue is that if a high resolution video is accessed from a standard/low definition device, it will not be played as the native video application can't handle it; this is mostly true on older/low-budget android devices, which have a standard or low display resolution.

My best guess was to filter the video source file based on the device width mediaquery, with something like `if width < 480 --> use low-res video` but this will probably exclude capable high end devices like iphones, galaxyS2+, and so on..

In the end I'm asking if there is something to query like "max video resolution support" or similar. I know there is something in the Android API, but I don't know if it can be used in this situation..

Below some links I've found for reference:

http://www.genuitec.com/mobile/docs/encodingVideo/encodingVideo.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html

Answer (score 2):

Android suggests to use CamcorderProfile for this according to this article:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#recommendations

They say:

> [...] a device's available video recording profiles can be used as a proxy for media playback capabilities. These profiles can be inspected using the CamcorderProfile class, which is available since API level 8.

I am now also using CamcorderProfile now as follows to detect maximum video width and height:

> ```
>   CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
>     Log.d(TAG, "Max Width: " + profile.videoFrameWidth);
>     Log.d(TAG, "Max Height: " + profile.videoFrameHeight);
> ```

At first I don't think this is a good solution because some devices need a permission to use the camera permission for this in the Android Manifest (for me this was the HTC Evo 3D):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>`

Unfortunately I also recognized that it does not work properly because for my Nexus S it says that the maxmium resolution would be 480x720 pixels but I was able to play a 1280x720 video from http://source.android.com/compatibility/downloads.html#cts-media-files
More accordingly the folder and filename within the zip archive was:
android-cts-media-1.0\bbb_short\1280x720\mp4_libx264_libfaac\bbb_short.ffmpeg.1280x720.mp4.libx264_1750kbps_30fps.libfaac_stereo_192kbps_48000Hz.mp4

Possibly this method helps you.

But I would appreciate any other method that fits better! Does anyone know another way?

Comment: this is quite interesting, but is that code java or javascript? As of now i partially resolved providing a low res video of 360p for any device below 480px width via mediaqueries, but of course its not the ideal solution..

Comment: It is Java-Code and CamcorderProfile(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) is available since API level 8 so that this methods normally can be used for nearly all devices. I have to correct myself because 1280x720 videos with a higher video bitrate than 1750 kbs were not possible to be played on the Nexus S so that the detected maximum resolution for videos (720x480 for my Nexus S).