# How to get Video Encoding Parameters details of an Android device?

Tags: android, video, encoding

I wanted to know if there is any API that provides supported video encoding parameters of an Android device. I have gone through the link http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html. The link mentions the supported formats but different devices may have different parameters support. I want to get those parameters in order to let the user know before hand that whether their device would be able to play back the videos within the app or not.

For example, HD feature may not be available on every device so if there is any API that provides that information then user can be informed that the device do not support it. Similarly, for other encoding parameters such as bitrate, frame rate, video resolution.

Comment: Will the information returned by CamcorderProfile API be used for the deciding the encoding parameters supported by the device ?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the answer I provided here:
[Detect max video resolution support for a mobile device on responsive website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16873883/detect-max-video-resolution-support-for-a-mobile-device-on-responsive-website?answertab=votes#tab-top)

It explains the solution in detail and is currently the only one unfortunately.